# Use one Ruby gem and not use another, in Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I am very new to Ruby.  I want to use one gem, a pre-released gem, instead of the original gem, in order to test it.  I have a Gemfile.  How do I do this?

I've been searching through the Bundler site, but I've only found more complicated things to do instead of more simple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify which version of a gem to use in your gem file.

```
gem 'gem_name', '~> 1.0.1' # <--- version
```

Then just run `bundle` to install and use that gem.

Comment: Did you mean `gem 'gem_name', '~> 1.0.1'`?

Answer (score 3):

```
gem 'gem_name'
```

Will use the latest version of the gem.

```
gem 'gem_name', '1.2.3'
```

Will force to use `1.2.3` version of the gem.

```
gem 'gem_name', '~> 1.2.3'
```

Will tell Bundler to use version of the gem `>= 1.2.3` but `< 1.3.0`

```
gem 'gem_name', '>= 1.2.3'
```

Speak to itself. The following signs are also available `< <= > =`

See [Bundler's doc](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rationale.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to find and use pre-release versions.

http://blog.agirorn.com/posts/1